# Merging n sheets with [date,data] format into one

Tags: excel, excel-2013

So I have those sheets: (non-empty data == ... )

Sheet A:

```
DATE       | DATA

01-07-2012 | ...

02-07-2012 | ...

03-07-2012 | ...

05-07-2012 | ...
```

Sheet B:

```
DATE       | DATA

02-07-2012 | ...

04-07-2012 | ...
```

Sheet C:

```
DATE       | DATA

01-07-2012 | ...
```

etc.

I want to merge all o them into following:

SheetOfMyDream: (day-by-day)

```
DATE       | DATA FROM A | DATE FROM B | DATE FROM C | etc.

01-07-2012 | ...         | empty       | ...

02-07-2012 | ...         | ...         | empty

03-07-2012 | ...         | empty       | empty

04-07-2012 | empty       | ...         | empty

05-07-2012 | ...         | empty       | empty ...
```

Thanks for your time and help! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=LEFT(ADDRESS(1;COLUMN()-1;2);1+(COLUMN()-1>26))
```

will tell you you are at row `B` that refers to sheet "A". Only works up to `ZZ`. You can replace it by `B$1` if that's where you keep the sheet names.

```
="'"& LEFT(ADDRESS(1;COLUMN()-1;2);1+(COLUMN()-1>26)) &"'!"
```

makes a reference to the sheet itself (`'A'!`), and

```
=VLOOKUP($A2;INDIRECT( "'"& LEFT(ADDRESS(1;COLUMN()-1;2);1+(COLUMN()-1>26)) &"'!" & "A:B");2;FALSE)
```

completes it.
Note: my system separator is ";", deal with it.

Comment: Oh yeah, you can wrap it up with an `IFERROR(;"empty")` too if that's what you're into.